# Heat capacity of mixtures is higher than their pure contituents?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, heat, mixtures

I'm currently studying the effects of how changing mixed-refrigerant compositions effects their heat capacity. Surprisingly, my data suggests that some combinations of mixed-refrigerants have heat capacities larger than their pure constituents. This seems to violate Kopp's Law which states:

> The molecular heat capacity of a solid compound is the sum of the atomic heat capacities of the elements composing it; the elements having atomic heat capacities lower than those required by the Dulong–Petit law retain these lower values in their compounds.

The mixed refrigerant compositions include: methane, ethane, propane and nitrogen. The graph below shows average, minumum and maximum heat capacity values over the temperature range from $\pu{130 K}$ to $\pu{280 K}$ and pressure range from $\pu{1 bar}$ to $\pu{100 bar}$.

Is there another possible explanation as for why a combination of the above components would have a higher capacity than their pure constituents? I was thinking along the lines of molecular interactions and deviations from the ideal gas law.

Here is a graph of my findings:

[image]

Note: I am using a gas physical property software for these calculations.

link: https://www.dnvgl.com/services/gasvle-8331

Comment: This is probably not so relevant here, but ideally you might want to provide a reference or a link to the github repo for the software you are using.

Comment: Are these mixtures of liquids or of vapors?

Comment: Liquid, vapour and liquid/vapour over the specified temperature and pressure range. Boiling points differ between each component quite drastically.

Comment: So you are measuring "apparent" heat capacity values over phase changes, correct?

Comment: Yes, this is totally theoretical. Though, I am assuming the software I am using is fairly accurate for these predictions. I am calcualting the heat capacity at each temperature over the full range of pressures (1bar-100bar in 1 bar steps).

Comment: Well, this includes the latent heats of vaporization, so you shouldn't be too surprised.

Comment: Could you expand upon this? Are you saying that the molecular interactions between the individual components are increasing the latent heat of the mixture (compared with the individual components? ).

Comment: Can you please give a specific example.

Comment: If you look at the average heat capacity of each componenet C1,C2,C3 and N2 compared with the average heat capacity of MR1, MR1 is a lot higher, despite being a mixture of the said individual components. Is this purely down to molecular interaction causing the latent heat to rise as the molecules are more strongly interacting?

Comment: By the way, I am not measuring the latent heat of vaporisation. Heat capacity and latent heat are two separate quantities. One being the energy absorbed as a function of temperature and the other the amount of energy required to induce a phase change.